# airflow db migrate is giving TypeError: SqlAlchemySessionInterface.__init__() missing 6 required positional

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, airflow

I've a step in my cicd pipeline that install airflow to test the dags loading. Since this morning has worked well. The steps are the following:

```
    - apt update -y
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install apache-airflow==2.7.3
    - export PATH=/root/.local/bin/:$PATH
    - airflow db migrate 
    - export AIRFLOW_HOME=/root/airflow
    - airflow variables import environments/local.json
    - python3 -m pytest -s dags/
```

From this morning i got the following error during db initialization

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 700, in _get_flask_db
AirflowDatabaseSessionInterface(app=flask_app, db=db, table="session", key_prefix="")
TypeError: SqlAlchemySessionInterface.**init**() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'sequence', 'schema', 'bind_key', 'use_signer', 'permanent', and 'sid_length'

here the complete traceback:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 57, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 53, in entrypoint
    StandaloneCommand().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/providers_configuration_loader.py", line 55, in wrapped_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 69, in run
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 179, in initialize_database
    db.initdb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 733, in initdb
    _create_db_from_orm(session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 718, in _create_db_from_orm
    _create_flask_session_tbl(engine.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 711, in _create_flask_session_tbl
    db = _get_flask_db(sql_database_uri)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 700, in _get_flask_db
    AirflowDatabaseSessionInterface(app=flask_app, db=db, table="session", key_prefix="")
TypeError: SqlAlchemySessionInterface.__init__() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'sequence', 'schema', 'bind_key', 'use_signer', 'permanent', and 'sid_length'
```

locally i tried some different versions of sqlalchemy and flask without any progress

Comment: Probably related: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/36895

Answer (score 14):

The issue is about the version of package `Flask-Session`. Temporary is limitation of airflow with `Flask-Session==0.6.0`

Solution:

```
pip install Flask-Session==0.5.0
```

Or you could use any version lower if you want but I suggest 0.5.0

There is github ticket for your issue if you want to investigate more:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/36883

Comment: This solution uninstall existing installation and install the new one.

Comment: Wow, it worked for me. I wasted lot of time in troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot man.  As a curious thought, I  also asked chat gpt and it gave me some serious mumble mumble. This is for the ones that says that stack overflow is over, no man, nothing beats your fellow nerd  community :).

Answer (score 4):

jonny Appleseed's comments helped me to solve the issue by fixing the version of Flask-Version.
see https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/36895

Comment: This was more helpful than the constraints answer. Constraints' purpose is to be installed first and then allow other dependencies to flexibly install over in development. You can't just do `pip install -r requirements.txt -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.1/constraints-3.10.txt"` because you would have to downgrade 100 libraries. Better to just pin the dependencies that break.

Comment: Your case also covered by [Installation from PyPI: Using own constraints](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#using-your-own-constraints). Install by use constraints, install/upgrade required packages, check, create new constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Airflow by provide constraints for specific Airflow and Python versions

```
pip install "apache-airflow==2.7.3” --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.3/constraints-3.11.txt"
```

For avoid surprises when upstream package is updated and breaks some critical part of the Airflow is follow [Installation from PyPI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) for additional details you might also might check mail [[Reminder] How to reproducibly install Airflow](https://lists.apache.org/thread/b8q1t3pvtky7y7mb2kjt4r2bz5bvz8qy) from the users mailing list.