# Getting error when using airflow db init in linux environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

```
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 700, in _get_flask_db
    AirflowDatabaseSessionInterface(app=flask_app, db=db, table="session", key_prefix="")
TypeError: SqlAlchemySessionInterface.__init__() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'sequence', 'schema', 'bind_key', 'use_signer', 'permanent', and 'sid_length'
```

I'm using `postgresql` database for the `sqlalchemy` connection in `airflow.cfg` but flask is throwing me this error when im using the db init command. Any help or suggestions?

I checked the connection in airflow info as well and it is showing up fine.

Expecting to start airflow with `postgresql` as meta data storage for airflow.

Comment: Please edit your question, add the full error message (all lines in the traceback), and add the shortest possible Python program which reproduces the error.

Comment: This may be a version incompatibility between *airflow* and *sqlalchemy*, but it's impossible to say without seeing your code and the full traceback in the error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846645/airflow-db-migrate-is-giving-typeerror-sqlalchemysessioninterface-init-mi